# combine columns containing empty strings into one column in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like below.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'apple': [1,0,1,0],
              'red grape': [1,0,0,1],
              'banana': [0,1,0,1]})
```

I need to create another column with combine these columns and separate with ';', like below:

```
    fruits  apple      red grape    banana
0   apple;red grape    1    1       0
1   banana             0    0       1
2   apple              1    0       0
3   red grape;banana   0    1       1
```

what I did was I converted 1/0 to string/empty string, then concatenate the columns

```
df['apple'] = df.apple.apply(lambda x: 'apple' if x==1 else '')
df['red grape'] = df['red grape'].apply(lambda x: 'red grape' if x==1 else '')
df['banana'] = df['banana'].apply(lambda x: 'banana' if x==1 else '')
df['fruits'] = df['apple']+';'+df['red grape']+';'+df['banana']

    apple   red grape   banana  fruits
0   apple   red grape           apple;red grape;
1                       banana  ;;banana
2   apple                       apple;;
3           red grape   banana  ;red grape;banana
```

The separators all screwed up because of the empty strings.  Also I want the solution to be more general.  For example, I might have lots of such columns to combine. Do not want to hardcode eveything...

Does anyone know the best way to do this? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.insert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html) for first column with [`DataFrame.dot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) for matrix multiplication with separator and last remove separator from right side by [`Series.str.rstrip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rstrip.html):

```
df.insert(0, 'fruits', df.dot(df.columns + ';').str.rstrip(';'))
print (df)
             fruits  apple  red grape  banana
0   apple;red grape      1          1       0
1            banana      0          0       1
2             apple      1          0       0
3  red grape;banana      0          1       1
```